# Spring Integration WebFlux Error Handling

Tags: spring, spring-integration, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

SI 5+ supports `WebFlux`, which means we can now build a reactive messaging system. However, it also means that the design has be thought through, and usual methods of error handling don't work. In a reactive flow, a message is a `Publisher`(`Flux`), and it doesn't throw an exception, but emits an error notification. Thus, the error channel header set on the message is useless because SI doesn't know that the `Flux` resulted in an error.
Consider the following code:

```
.handle(WebFlux.outboundGateway(m -> m.getPayload().toString(), webClient)
    .expectedResponseType(YelpRecord.class)
    .httpMethod(GET)
    .mappedRequestHeaders(ACCEPT)
    .replyPayloadToFlux(true))
.handle((GenericHandler<Flux<YelpRecord>>) (flux, headers) ->
    flux
            .doOnError(t -> log.error(t.getMessage(), t))
            .doAfterTerminate(() ->
                    log.info("Completed streaming from: {}.", headers.get(DOWNLOAD_URI_HEADER))
            )
            .onBackpressureBuffer(
                    yelpArtifactoryProperties.getOnBackpressureBufferSize(),
                    BufferOverflowStrategy.ERROR)
)
```

What is missing in the above code snippet is sending the exception to the error channel configured on the message from `doOnError`. How can we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `((MessageChannel) header.getErrorChannel()).send(...)` work for you there in the `.doOnError()`?

The point is that you are right and this `Flux` in the message payload is already out of control by the Framework and if you would like to deal with its errors, you have to do that yourself. That is already your code with a `doOnError()` therefore the Framework can't help you already with something automatic.

Comment: The `ErrorMessagePublisher` also looks interesting to me?

Comment: Yes, then `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` would be better. This one can resolve `errorChannel` from the headers as well, not only be stick with the pre-configured one like in case of its super.

Comment: So, autowire `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` and call `handleError`?

Comment: Sounds like that! `.doOnError(errorPublisher::handleError)` and that's it! But need still to keep in mind that the whole `Flux` is going to terminate in case of such an error. You can't continue processing when only one event is erroneous: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#error.handling

Comment: With reactor 3.2, we can! See [this](https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/16/sneak-peek-at-reactor-core-3-2-with-milestone-1#introducing-error-strategy)

Comment: Yeah... That's cool! Don't have chance these days for reading :-)

Comment: That didn't work. `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler' available`.

Comment: No, I assumed the framework would do that for me. I can just create a new one in the class, no problem. Will try and accept the answer if that works.

Comment: Yeah... We definitely may consider to add one by default. Since we more and more go the reactive way that might be useful to publish error global way